# What does decimal lag point mean in PACF graph produced by R?

Tags: time-series

When I plot PACF graph of my data it is giving decimal numbers on X-axis. What does that mean?

0.08 lag dos it imply it depends on 0.08th segment of the day?
[image]

Comment: Read about the `frequency` argument  in `?ts`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scale of the horizontal-axis is in terms of complete seasonal periods. It looks like you might have daily data with a seasonal period of 365. So the horizontal axis is in terms of years. 0.08 lags means 0.08 years, or equivalently 0.08*365=29 days.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose you  are finding out the pacf for the time-series, `series_x`. Just write: `pacf(series_x[1:length(series_x)])`.  That will give the lags in integers.

If you need to find the cross correlation between the two series, where time-series_x is `series_x` and time-series_y is `series_y`, (note that the length of series_x must be equal to the length of series_y) just write:

```r
library(forecast) 

fit  <- auto.arima(series_x) 
yhat <- residuals(Arima(series_y, model=fit))
res  <- ccf(fit$residuals[1:nrow(series_x)], yhat[1:nrow(series_y)], 
            lag.max=12, type=c("correlation","covariance"), plot=TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your suggestions , the first answer here has well explained the solution of the problem . I have just extended to that if someone wants integer lags in pacf and ccf plots .